# Usar distinct y ordenar por una relación con JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Tengo estos 3 beans:

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>(0);
    private String login;
    private String password;
    private Integer id;
    private DestinationGroup destinationGroup;
    ....
    // Getters and setters
```

DestinationGroup.java

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "grupo_destinatario")
public class DestinationGroup implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;
    private Integer id;
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
    ....
    // Getters and setters
```

Role.java

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "perfil")
public class Role extends AbstractModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;
    private Integer id;
    ....
    // Getters and setters
```

Quiero obtener todos los usuarios que no tengan el perfil "admin", ordenados por el nombre de su grupo de destino ("destinationGroup"). Para eso utilizo este código:

UserTest.java

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<User> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(User.class);
Root<User> root = criteriaQuery.from(User.class);
Join<User, Role> path = root.join("roles", JoinType.LEFT);
Expression<Object> filter = path.get("name");
Predicate localPredicate = criteriaBuilder.notEqual(filter, "admin");
criteriaQuery.where(localPredicate);
Join<User, DestinationGroup> path2 = root.join("destinationGroup", JoinType.LEFT);
Expression<Object> sort = path2.get("name");
List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
orders.add(criteriaBuilder.asc(sort));
criteriaQuery.orderBy(orders);
TypedQuery<User> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<User> users = query.getResultList();
```

El problema es que eso devuelve resultados repetidos, en caso de que algún usuario tenga más de un rol. Para evitarlo y conseguir obtener sólo un resultado por usuario, he añadido a la segunda línea del código de test ".distinct(true)":

```
CriteriaQuery<User> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(User.class).distinct(true);
```

Pero entonces salta una excepción: "para SELECT DISTINCT, las expresiones en ORDER BY deben aparecer en la lista de resultados". Lógicamente no puedo eliminar el orderBy pero necesito que los resultados no salgan repetidos. Cómo puedo solucionar esto? Se pueden añadir relaciones al distinct?

Comment: No estoy del todo seguro porque hace tiempo que no juego con el Criteria API, pero prueba a hacer *fetch* de `destinationGroup`; simplemente añade `root.fetch("destinationGroup");` en lugar del `join`

Comment: Perfecto, con tu sugerencia funciona perfectamente. La línea que he cambiado es esta: Join<?, ?> path2 = (Join<?,?) root.fetch("destinationGroup", JoinType.LEFT); Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Tiene que ser Criteria API precisamente o puede ser con JPQL?

Comment: Quiero usar criteria API para separar totalmente la programación del SQL. Pero como comentaba, con la solución de @SJuan76 el problema está resuelto.